# Write access to Linux ext3 partition from Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, filesystem

I've a dual boot system with Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7. I can access my Linux files (partition format is ext3) from Windows, but I cannot write to them. I've edited the properties of the Linux drive from `ext2fsd`, **Properties > Security**, etc and everything in sight has full control.

When I look at the properties of the Linux folder from Windows Explorer, again, everybody has write access. But whenever I try to write to the disk, I'm told that the disk is write-protected.

On the Linux side, the permissions setting on the folder is 777.

Comment: Have a look on `fsproxy`.

Comment: Are you sure the partition is not ext4? You will have to check in Linux - it will appear as ext3 in ext2fsd. "If you want to enable write support for an EXT4 filesystem, select "Ext2 Management", uncheck the "Mount volume in readonly mode" box and then click Apply:" [Using Ext2Fsd](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/08/access-ext4-ext3-or-ext2-partitions-in.html)

Comment: I would recommend another file system, if you want write access from Windows (and Ubuntu). Maybe the following link can help, [Full compatibility with Linux, Windows and MacOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706#952706)