# How do I copy a file larger than 4GB to a USB flash drive?

Tags: usb-drive, copy

I am trying to copy a 6GB file to a USB flash drive but it won't copy.

Comment: Is the USB drive formatted with FAT32? That file system does not support files larger than 4GB. You have to format it differently then, e.g. as NTFS. Beware that formatting deletes all data on the drive.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

This is due to FAT32 limitation. Files larger than 4GB *cannot* be stored on a FAT32 volume. Formatting the flash drive as exFAT or NTFS will resolve this issue.

WARNING: Back up your data. Formatting will delete all the data on your device.

Comment: BTW, formatting the flash drive as `ext3` is also an option

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes, but it's not very usable on some proprietary OSes ;)

Comment: @Ruslan: I second this. Using ext3/4 on Windows was more painful than using exFat and NTFS in Linux.

Comment: Even though it is a Microsoft creation, there's a lot to be said for exFAT.  As others have noted it is handled by all three desktop OSs, therefore you will tend to maximize your interoperability.   In addition it was designed for use on large flash drives.  Citation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT  In particular, because it can mark a file as contiguous, and thereby avoid having to touch the FAT, it works extremely efficiently in the OPs use case: handling a very large file.

Comment: In order of compatibility with the most devices and operating systems, FAT32 > NTFS > exFAT > other (ext, HFS etc).  I feel that NTFS beats out exFAT for support on devices like media players, and I use it for any portable drive bigger than a small thumb drive.

Comment: @dgnuff you mean, all three *major* desktop OSs :)

Comment: @Russo: "cannot" is one word. "Back up" is two words, when a verb, as here. Also in English you say "data on your device" not "data in your device".

Comment: @psmears At first I was about to ask why you've written this in a comment instead of doing an edit suggestion. Then I discovered you actually had suggested useful improvements to the post (though it's possible to write _can not_  when _not_ is [emphasised](http://www.write.com/writing-guides/general-writing/word-choice/cannot-versus-can-not/) ), which were for some reason rejected by the OP :(

Comment: I am sorry for not accepting @psmears edit suggestions. I didn't think fixing "can NOT" to "cannot", and "backup" to "back up" is the reason worthy of editing an answer. I specially tried to emphasize on the NOT part from "can NOT".  I have fixed the "data on your device" part, if that matters.

Comment: @Russo There is [wide disagreement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253326/1394393) about accepting minor edits on other people's answers, but you should *never* avoid editing your *own* answer when you know something is wrong with it. If there's objectively a problem, fix it.

Comment: Advice: if you want to emphasize "cannot", bolding it or italicizing it will do the job better than separating the word and capitalizing part of it. ;)

Comment: @dessert: Yes, that's right - "can not" has a different meaning. If you want to say "it is impossible to store files larger than 4GB...", as the OP presumably intends, then it needs to be "cannot" - otherwise it is saying something else. And especially if you want emphasis on the negative - the emphatic opposite of *can* is *cannot* (whole word in italics) - saying "can *not*"  (or, worse, using capitals) again gives a different meaning.

Answer (score 103):

If you don't want to reformat your USB drive or need it to be FAT32 you can simply **split** your big file into parts. Most archive managers come with the split option and for the command line there's `split`, e.g. for your case:

```
split -b4294967295 /path/to/input.file /path/to/pen/drive/output.file.
```

See [`man split`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/split.1.html) for the full documentation.
This will create the following files:

```
4,0G output.file.aa
1,6G output.file.ab
```

The filesize of `output.file.aa` matches exactly the maximum file size of your FAT32 formatted USB drive, which is **4 [Gibibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte)** (GiB, that's **not** the same as Gigabyte GB) **minus 1 Byte**.
<sub>Thanks to [Gilles](https://askubuntu.com/users/1059/gilles) for this important addition.</sub>

---

Before you can access the file again you need to **merge** its parts first. On Linux systems you can do so with:

```
cat output.file.* > input.file
```

<sup>If you're afraid that this could sort the files incorrectly read [In Bash, are wildcard expansions guaranteed to be in order?](https://serverfault.com/questions/122737/in-bash-are-wildcard-expansions-guaranteed-to-be-in-order)</sup>
The corresponding command on Windows systems is:

```
copy /b output.file.aa+output.file.ab input.file
```

---

Along with many other useful GNU utilities `split` can be installed in Windows too, see [GNU utilities for Win32](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net).

Comment: I bet half of the upvotes I get here are just because of GiB vs. GB. ;)

Comment: I'd have upvoted for `split` even without the distinction between GiB and GB.  But I'll send an attaboy for that...

Comment: @dessert I would expect that to get you only about 7.4% more upvotes.

Comment: I upvoted because reformatting the drive just to be able to move one large file is a horrible answer when `split` exists precisely for this purpose and is not required on the receiving end.  FAT32 is the lingua franca of USB drives for a reason.

Comment: I think `-b 4095M` would be far simpler and achieve the same as the `bc` command. In Bash one could also use shell arithmetic: `$(((4<<30)-1))`.

Comment: I did this split with a file that was about 19 GB large, and now I have the problem that I cannot merge the split parts since I get the error `cat: write error: File too large`...

Answer (score 49):

### Problem: FAT32 has a 4GiB limit for file size

Different scenarios and files systems are examined looking for alternatives taking into account

- the file size problem
- which operating systems that should read/write the USB drive

### Linux only

If you intend to use the drive only with Ubuntu (and other linux distros), it is a good idea to use a **linux file system**, for example **ext4**. This way you might get higher read/write speed (depending on which process is the bottleneck), and you will get higher flexibility concerning ownership and permissions.

- You can use the GUI program **`gparted`** to create the **ext4** file system.

### Full compatibility with Linux, Windows and MacOS

Windows has problems with linux file systems, and I think MacOS has problems both with linux file systems and **NTFS**. So if you want 'full compatibility' for reading and writing, only **FAT32**, **UDF** and **exFAT** remain.

- ***FAT32** has a 4GiB (gibibyte, base 2) limit for file size.*
- Can be created in all three operating systems.
- Maintain (repair) in Windows, if you have access to Windows.
- Can be maintained in Ubuntu with `dosfsck`, that comes with the package `dosfstools`,

  ```
       sudo apt-get install dosfstools

       sudo dosfsck -a /dev/sdxn  # least destructive option
       sudo dosfsck -r /dev/sdxn  # more powerful option
  ```

  where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number, for example `/dev/sdb1` for the first partition in drive b.
- ***exFAT** is another option.* It is new compared to **FAT32** and **UDF** and claimed to work well
- natively with Windows
- with MacOS
- with Linux

### More about exFAT

#### Edit August 2021:

**Since this answer was written, the support for exFAT is bundled in the new versions of standard Ubuntu, so you need no extra packages to run it.**

#### end of edit

I have started to test **exFAT** in Ubuntu. I intend to edit this answer, when I have more experience of using it. Let us start with the following **links**,

- [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT)

**ExFAT** is a proprietary file system of Microsoft optimized for

```
> embedded systems because it is lightweight and is better suited for
> solutions that have low memory and low power requirements, and can be
> implemented in firmware.
```

- [How to get a drive formatted with exfat working (in Ubuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370398/how-to-get-a-drive-formatted-with-exfat-working/374627#374627)

and this **command line** to install [read/write] support for exFAT in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse
```

- Can be created in Windows and MacOS *and in Linux* with the following command line

  ```
   sudo mkfs.exfat -n YOUR-LABEL /dev/sdxi
  ```

where `x` is the drive letter and `i` is the partition number, for example `/dev/sdb1`.

- Can be maintained in Windows.

My first **test results**:

- Creating the exFAT file system worked well in Ubuntu (16.04 LTS (64-bit), installed system with the Xenial kernel series (4.4.0-93-generic), up to date).
- Writing and reading a file greater than 4 GiB were successful. Ubuntu and exFAT co-operated correctly and fast (I checked with `md5sum` and the speed was limited by the USB system).
- Ubuntu and Windows could read what was created in the other operating system. (I have no MacOS for testing, and have to rely on the reports from other people.)

### Windows

So if you want full read/write access from Ubuntu and Windows, I would suggest that you use **NTFS**, which has journaling and is very debugged and polished as the [proprietary] file system for Windows. (It is also possible to use **exFAT**.)

- In Ubuntu you can use the GUI program **`gparted`** to create an NTFS file system.
- In Windows it is easy to create NTFS and exFAT file systems (they are native).

---

- ***UDF** probably lacks tools to repair the file system,*
- FOSS
- Maybe it is possible to find repair tools in Windows via this link: [fsck tools for UDF](https://github.com/JElchison/format-udf/wiki/fsck-tools-for-UDF), and there is some tool available as source code
- Can be created in Ubuntu
- Compatible with linux style links.
- Compatible with linux style permissions. You can create and modify permissions of individual files (which is not possible with FAT and NTFS).
- A UDF partition will not be prompted for formatting by Windows 10 (while the linux ext4 file system is affected, and can be destroyed by mistake).
- How to create and use UDF: [Using the UDF as a successor of FAT for USB sticks](http://tanguy.ortolo.eu/blog/article93/usb-udf)

  So, to use it, assuming your USB stick is `/dev/sdx`:

1. Install the package `udftools`

   ```
           sudo apt-get install udftools
   ```
2. Create a partition table and one partition with **`gparted`** or **`gnome-disks`**
3. Wipe the first mibibyte of the target partition with the risky `dd` (double-check the command line!)

   ```
           sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx1 bs=1M count=1
   ```
4. Run **`mkudffs`**,

   ```
           sudo mkudffs -b 512 --media-type=hd --lvid=my-label /dev/sdx1
   ```

   Wipe the first mibibyte of the partition to erase the previous file system information (or other remaining data), to prevent you USB stick from being detected as a FAT after it has been formatted with UDF.

   The `-b 512` is to force a file system block size equal to the USB stick's physical block size, as required by the UDF specification. Adapt it if you have the luck of having a USB stick with a more appropriate block size.

   After that, your USB stick will be usable for reading and writing with GNU/Linux but also with current versions of Windows (read-only with the outdated version XP). Unfortunately this version of UDF created in Linux cannot be managed by MacOS (tested in several versions of MacOS in November 2020).

### MacOS

#### Edit August 2021: HFS+ (journaled)

**Since this answer was written, I discovered that Linux can read and write HFS+ (journaled)**, so use Disk Utility.app on your Mac to format the partition with HFS+ (journaled) in order to have a drive (for example an external drive) that can transfer or share data between Ubuntu and MacOS.

See: https://superuser.com/questions/392702/which-file-system-to-use-in-between-osx-and-linux

#### end of edit

In MacOS it is possible to use **FAT32** and **exFAT**.

You can also use **ext4 with a workaround, Ubuntu Server with an SSH server in a virtual machine**. (I think the same workaround would work also with Windows.) This may be worthwhile when you intend to access a lot of files via the drive and its file system, but probably not with a small USB2 pendrive.

See this link: [Using ext4 on OS X Yosemite, the long but safe way](https://blog.thibmaekelbergh.be/2015/04/08/using-ext4-on-os-x-yosemite-the-long-but-safe-way.html)

Comment: AFAIR Windows XP can't write to UDF volumes. It's not much of a problem nowadays but still worth noting, just in case.

Comment: macOS mounts everything as read-only NTFS by default (I presume Apple don't believe the NTFS write support is sufficiently reliable.)

Comment: @gsnedders I expect they just don't believe in Windows.

Comment: @wizzwizz4, You may be right ;-) But there are several reports about problems/risks with writing from non-windows operating systems to NTFS. For this reason, if you have a dual boot Ubuntu + Windows system, you are recommended to use a separate **data** partition with NTFS instead of writing directly from Ubuntu to the Windows system partition (C: in Windows).

Comment: @sudodus Personally I've had no problems with everything from heavy NTFS partition management to manipulating Streams from Debian, but I appreciate being safe with data. Also, **I have a backup**, so it doesn't matter if I lose old data (I can just copy it from the backup).

Comment: @wizzwizz4, I agree about being safe with data. Also, I have a [fairly recent] **backup** :-)

Comment: Note: you can use exfat on MacOS without problems (it can even format the drive as exfat). exfat is also becoming the default for larger flash disks / memory cards as well.

Comment: @SztupY, So maybe we should modify the recommendation of a common file system in favour of **exfat**? -- I do not run MacOS, so I have no direct experience of it. But I can do some tests with exfat in Ubuntu (and look for comments via the internet).

Comment: I didn't know about `UDF` before! Is this format usually supported in "multimedia" devices as well (such as TVs, PlayStation, etc.)?

Comment: @Dan, I think it was designed for DVDs to replace `ISO 9660`. I think but I'm not sure, that it is usually supported in "multimedia" devices. There are several versions of `UDF`, and the read/write version we are talking about here might or might not be supported. Try if it works, and let us know :-) See this link, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format

Comment: @sudodus I don't know how easy it is to use exfat on modern Linux distributions (I believe it should be fairly painless), but on both (modern) Windows and OSX platforms it's probably the best cross-platform solution (works out of the box, full R/W support, able to format to exfat, etc.) nowadays. Also larger memory cards (SDXC) use exfat, and devices (like DSLRs) that can accept SDXC can also use exfat

Comment: exFAT works well for me so far (in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) :-)

Answer (score 12):

Having had a simular issue and unwilling to reformat the USB stick, I just used an archiver. More or less all modern GUIs (such as File Roller, 7Zip, etc.) or CLIs allow for splitting the archive file. Set the split limit below the FAT boundary (that somewhat 4GB), for speed you can choose a low compression rate, even "store", i.e. do not compress at all, an voila!

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to a Windows machine you can convert you USB-stick file system without formatting.
You should use Windows command line as follows:
press `Win + R`, type `cmd` -> `OK`, in the open window enter command `convert X: /FS:ntfs` where `X:` is the letter for your mounted USB-stick. In less than a minute it is ready. Enjoy.

Comment: This method can be useful :-) But converting a file system might be risky, so I would recommend to **backup** everything important on the USB-stick before converting. By the way, have you used this method? Does it keep the files? Does it work also to/from exfat?

Comment: I used this method several times, all the files were readable after this procedure. This utility works only to convert to NTFS, not vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Reformatting or using split are great options, or you could try using zip to compress the file, just know that some files are already compressed, so zipping them will make them larger. (Also you may lose file ownership, timestamps etc.)