# How to view FAT32 Ubuntu files from Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, xubuntu, fat32

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC a while ago, and I really like the new OS.  I've noticed that I can access all data on the hard drive from Ubuntu, but I can't find Ubuntu files from Windows.  I set up Ubuntu with the FAT32 file system (yes, I know), which is supported by Windows, and no partitions are encrypted.  If anyone can tell me how I can allow Windows to view the files on the other partition, that would be great.  If I could do this without a third-party application, it would be even better.

Here's what my disk manager sees:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgi22.png

Comment: Don't install any drivers on Windows that allow you to read/write to Ubuntu EXT2/3/4 partitions. You'll corrupt Ubuntu. Best to create a separate NTFS partition that both OS's can access.

Comment: Disable hibernation in windows.

Comment: Can you show us your (working) fstab?

Comment: Why have you tagged this question under `xubuntu`? Is it xubuntu you have installed or ubuntu?

Comment: You may get some useful tips from the following link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706?s=2|6.3116#952706 ; It is a good idea to have a separate `data` partition for sharing data with Window. There are alternatives to FAT32: NTFS, exFAT and UDF. Windows should read them all, if the file systems are healthy (not corrupted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FAT32 file system is supported by Windows. The partition isn't being shown probably because it is missing a letter. Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open Run. Write **diskmgmt.msc** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
It'll open the Disk Management app. There you'll find the FAT32 partition, right click on it and assign any letter to it. Hopefully, it'll be shown then.

However you can install Ubuntu on an EXT4 partition and still access it in Windows using a program called [Linux Reader](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/).

Answer (score 2):

You seem to admit this in your question, but using FAT32 is not a good idea for installing your Ubuntu system.  It doesn't even have basic security features expected by Linux.

It is better to set up a system partition for each OS using an appropriate filesystem for that OS, and then have a separate partition which is to be shared by both OSes.  While FAT32 is an option for such a partition, NTFS is probably a better choice now as FAT32 still has that 4GB file size limit, very relevant these days, and it's a little easier to corrupt if your computer doesn't shut down cleanly.  NTFS is now supported well by most operating systems, including Linux.

That said, I don't know why your FAT32 partition isn't showing on Windows.  That may be a Windows issue that you'll need to sort out, if you do want to continue trying this.