# Is a FAT32 partition able to use non-ASCII characters for names of files and directories the same way as Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, fat32

I have installed the Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7 systems at the same PC. I prepare to change all names of files and directories to ASCII so that I can use correctly a united probably FAT32 partition. I feel as if I am trying to go back to the DOS. Shall it be necessary after upgrading to the Windows 10 (and resolving the GRUB problems)? Is there a difference between Windows 7 and Windows 10 FAT32 or similar filesystems which is useful for that purpose? (I guess that Ubuntu uses the UTF-8 coding. Microsoft technical contact has hang up the phone after I had asked a question about that difference between Windows 7 and Windows 10.)

Comment: See the following link concerning common file systems for different operating systems, https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706#952706 ; I do not know the details about how the different file systems cooperate with the different operating systems *with non-ascii characters in the file names*, but it is a good idea in general to avoid characters that are interpreted in a special way in any of the operating systems that are used.

Comment: This question is about difference between two Windows versions. IMHO Microsoft MSDN or Technet forums can provide you an authoritative answer, straight from the beast's mouth, so to say. On SE a suitable site is maybe Superuser.