# Moving data between two OS's on the same desktop?

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, ssd

I have Installed Xubuntu on my 1T SSD and have Windows on a smaller SSD within the same desktop. I want to transfer files between the two locally; not mirror the files like a backup. Is there a good program for this? Or maybe a simpler way? I want to learn and use Xubuntu as my main OS. Cheers.

Comment: Create a shared NTFS data partition. But Windows 8 or 10 use fast start up  or hibernation. And that keeps all NTFS partitions mounted so you cannot see the NTFS partition. So just make sure fast start up is off.

Comment: The following link describes some alternatives for common partitions, https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706#952706 ; It is a good idea to put the label 'data' on the common partition (or some other label, that helps you identify it.

Answer (score 1):

[Create](https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Partition) an additional NTFS/FAT32 formatted partition and store your data on it. Both Windows and Ubuntu can access NTFS/FAT32 partition. Make sure [fast startup](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-turn-on-or-off-fast-startup-in-windows-10/) is turned off in Windows (8, 8.1, 10).

Alternatively from Windows you can use [Linux Reader](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) to access partitions formatted with ext4 (the partition format Ubuntu uses as default). But never make changes to any file within Ubuntu root partition (the partition where Xubuntu is installed) while on Windows.