# Unable to merge two partitions of Pendrive using GParted!

Tags: usb-drive, partitioning, format

## GParted is unable to merge a partitioned 16 GB Pendrive.

### How do I merge the two partitions as shown in the following picture?

[image: Here shown is a screenshot of my pen drive partitions as shown by the GParted software.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try under windows and if it's recognizable try to use `'diskpart'` to create partition and format usb normally

Comment: Thanks, that worked in windows pc, it first asked to format the drive immediately after putting the usb in windows pc and then it became normal.

Comment: good it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

### USB pendrive

I suggest that you install and use **mkusb-dus** to restore [the USB drive] to a standard storage device. This creates an MSDOS partition table and a partition with a FAT32 file system.

See the following links

- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)
- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)

  [image]

### USB hard disk drive or solid state drive

In this case you may want more than one partition and you may want some other file system (not FAT32).

- Use **mkusb-dus** to wipe the first mibibyte,

  [image]
- Install **gparted**

  ```
  sudo apt install gparted
  ```

  and create

  - the partition table, old MSDOS or new GUID partition table (GPT),
  - partitions and
  - file systems.

  [image]
- The following link adds tips about file systems,

  [Alternative file systems (to FAT32 with a 4GiB limit for file size)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706#952706)