# Rsync replacement

Tags: bash, rsync, find

After spending time trying to make `rsync` work, I decided to use something else. I have a tree of files at /home that I want to backup to a 64G USB stick once a day, using the same tree structure, but only copy over the ones that don't exist in destination ( and preserve timestamps ).

The problem:

Even if a source folder has only one new file (and 400 old ones), my rsync always finds a reason to copy about half of them over to dest.

I experimented with something along the lines of this

```
find /home/me/a/r/z/ -type f -mmin 400 | xargs -0 -I{} cp '{}' /media/usb-id/$( cut -d / -f 4- {} )
```

Lots of mistakes, I know. I use "4" with cut because that's where the tree starts in destination (`/media/usb-id/r/z/whatever`). I think I should be using `sed` somehow in all of this. Any ideas?

Obvious error:

```
cut: {}: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could you tell us what do you want to have? Backup one folder to external drive? What kind of file system do you have on this external drive - ntfs?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `rsync` works correctly and you should rather ask how to make it work correctly for you instead of asking for an alternative. Rsync is skipping files based on modification time & file size. Maybe have a look on your usb if these somehow changed and why. As an alternative try to use `-checksum` switch. This will be slower but in case your mod time on your stick changes whyever this might help.

Comment: How do you know which files are actually copied over by `rsync`? If you mean the output of `rsync -P`, that’s *supposed* to show every file IIRC – it has to loop over every file to check for changes, obviously.

Comment: When using rsync for backups, you might find the options `-RavC` to be a good formula.

Comment: Its about updating a tree structure in a usb stick ( vfat ) starting at /r ( /r/z, /r/t, /r/z/x etc ) using a similar structure from /dev/sda1 ( Ubuntu 10.04 ) as a source. I know rsync is the way to go but now that I've gone down this road it would be interesting to see how this can be implemented in an other, not so intuitive way.

Comment: Probably the timestamp resolution is not the same on the source and destination filesystems. rsync has an option for that case (--modify-window=)

Comment: Are you going from ext4 to ext4? Using Windows formats like NTFS or FAT32 is not recommended as it does not support ownership & permissions. Not sure then about timestamps.

Comment: ext4 to vfat. Tried formatting the thing to ntfs, copying the files over the first time was way too slow.

Comment: As oldfred states change your USB from FAT to ext4 and only changed/new files will be backed up.

Comment: Likely related: [rsync not working between NTFS/FAT and EXT](/q/112863/175814)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `sudo rsync -Havn` between `ext4` file systems

is the best way to go, if you want to preserve permissions and ownership of the files. This can be very important, because the linux system depends on it. But it is not important for personal data files.

I would recommend to start with a 'dry run'

```
sudo rsync -Havn source/ target
```

and if it looks good, remove the option `n` and do it,

```
sudo rsync -Hav source/ target
```

It preserves 'everything', so you can copy a whole linux operating system from one `ext4` file system to another `ext4` file system. And you can copy only a limited directory tree that way too.

---

An alternative to `ext4` on the target drive is `udf`, if you must be able to read it from Windows. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706#952706). The `udf` file system can manage the ownership and permissions (and time stamps) of linux file systems.

But there is a drawback with `udf`. There is no well known tool to repair it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their replys, all very helpfull. I still find it interesting that everybody is such a huge fan of rsync and not really interested in experimenting with an alternative way to fix this, like a find/xargs combination. I thought it might be fun. I will try the -checksum and -modify-window options and probably end up formatting the stick to ext4, because for some reason ext4 to ntfs file transfers started out at 7MB/sec and ended up at 90kb/sec...

Comment: It is also my experience, that linux writes slowly to NTFS. NTFS is a proprietary file system of Microsoft, and the linux driver for it is probably some kind of reverse engineered code, that it not as efficient as the free drivers for linux file systems. (FAT32 is also owned by Microsoft, but the original FAT code was probably free (long ago) and also rather simple, so the linux drivers for FAT can be quite efficient.) - Anyway, many of us like `rsync`, and we hope that you will not only get along with it, but start liking it too :-)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I like rsync just fine. I just want to get the job done, when I want it done, no matter what the tool is. Didnt have the time or energy to keep on typing commands that didnt work. Plus the vastness of Linux still overwhelms me occasionally.

Comment: You are welcome @YetAnotherNewbieSort-of :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at this: https://github.com/Fitus/Zaloha.sh. It is a find-based shell script, also based on the same idea as yours (but it is a little bit more complex than your one-liner, as you might expect) ...