# Accessing MacOS Big Sur files with a ubuntu bootable USB key

Tags: files, live-usb, mac

I made a Ubuntu Live USB key so I can access my MacOS files without having to go to through the trouble of trying to access hidden folders and what-not. The Ubuntu usb works fine, other than the fact that I can't access MacOS files. I get this error code when I try to open the MacOS drive. [Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9okQk.png) Any ideas on how to go about this, I'm OK with creating a new other type of live USB key to access my mac files btw.

Comment: APFS is a proprietary file system.  There is a GitHub project that purports to read and write to APFS: https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse

Comment: You can create a [small] partition with a suitable file system for sharing files between Ubuntu and MacOS. `exFAT` and `HFS+` (journaled) are two candidate file systems that can be read and written by both operating systems. Maybe it is easiest to have `exFAT` on a USB drive and write to it from the MacOS and then read from it into Ubuntu, but `HFS+` (journaled) is more robust. See more details at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706#952706) (scroll down to the paragraph about MacOS).

Comment: No pictures of text please include the text in the question.