# I'm dual booting Ubuntu and MacOS. Can I access my mac files on ubuntu and vice versa?

Tags: dual-boot

I'm dual booting Ubuntu 22.04 and MacOS BigSur (11.6.1). Can I access my mac files on ubuntu and vice versa?

I've never dual booted before, always used VMs in the past. I created three partitions on my mac (8gb for swap, and the rest is half for mac and half for ubuntu).

Apologies if this is a dumb question and thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be a good idea to create a 'data' partition with the exFAT file system, which can be managed by Ubuntu and MacOS. The idea is to keep files, that you want to access from both operating systems on that 'data'  partition (you can use the *label* `data` or some other label, that helps identifying it. See also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706#952706), that should be OK even if it might be a little old now (scroll down to find relevant paragraphs).

Comment: Thanks for the info! I did this, using MacOS I created another partition, 32gb called data-share. The 32gb was pulled from my macos partitian. Unfortunately now when I boot and hold down the option key to use refind to switch OSs, only Ubuntu shows up. My macOS is nowhere to be found. Do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: If you move the head end of a partition, it might not be found. If you move the tail end things should work. But it is possible that you did not properly do all the steps necessary, shrink the file system and after that shrink the partition (the container of the file system). Anyway, maybe it will work if you run `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu. Maybe you must repair the file system of MacOS. -- Editing partitions is risky, errors can happen to anyone, also experienced users. I hope you have a good backup of everything that you cannot afford to lose.