# Can't copy a file into pen drive after image is created using Startup Disk Creator

Tags: boot, 20.04, startup-disk-creator

I used `Startup Disk Creator` to create an image of [FreeDOS](https://www.freedos.org/download/).
My pen drive has 4gb. Freedos image has 1,4Mb.
After burning the pen drive with this image I can't copy additional files because the `Startup Disk Creator` limits the pen drive to the size of the image.

Context:
I want to use `FreeDOS` to upload a BIOS of an old computer. In two different sources, they recommended creating an image of `FreeDOS` and then I needed to copy the `Bios .exe file` to the root of the image created.

Comment: Not sure Startup Disk Creator is the right tool for ?burning? anything. I've used [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) to write freedos to a USB in the past.

Comment: You might need to use something like [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) for that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably 'only' that you have a partition table and a file system, that is not made for storage. You can use a tool to create a fresh partition table and a file system for storage. You can do that with `gparted`. You may have to install it,

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install gparted
```

If still problems, you can use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), which has an option to create a simple partition table with a FAT32 file system. This can work even when other tools cannot manage the drive.

After that it should be possible not only to store files, but `gparted` can create several different file systems.

If you intend to use the drive only with Linux, I suggest that you use a Linux filesystem, for example `ext4`.

If you want the drive to be compatible with Windows you can use the old standard FAT32 (with max file size 4 GiB) or the newer file systems NTFS or exFAT without file size limits.

Links:

[Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

[How do I copy a file larger than 4GB to a USB flash drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706#952706)

Comment: With `gparted` I couldn't copy the file. With `mkusb` I was able to burn the `img` and copy the BIOS file. However, there was an error in boot, and I could not update the BIOS.

Comment: How big is the exe file (that should update the BIOS)? I downloaded `FD13-FullUSB.zip`, extracted `FD13FULL.img`, cloned it to a pendrive and there are 141 516 800 bytes free in `C:` Do you need more free space? If there is a boot problem, did you boot in BIOS mode alias CSM alias legacy mode (*not* in UEFI mode)?

Comment: If `C:` is too small (not enough space for the exe file), you can use `gparted` to create a second partition with FAT32, with a size that uses all remaining drive space 'behind' the first partition (C: in DOS, /dev/sdx1 in Ubuntu). That should be approximately  3.5 GB, enough for the exe file. I checked that FREEDOS can see (read and write files using) such a second partition on the USB drive. Its drive letter may be D: or E: or ... depending on what other FAT file systems there are in the computer. For example, an EFI system partition may be seen as D: